# Flex password field check

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm programming in Flex. I wish to have two password fields, and validate that they contain the same password.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom component with two fields and a submit button. (Also any validators you might need.) Don't enable the submit button unless both fields validate and are identical.

Basically, just compare the text property of the first `TextInput` field to the text property of the second. Also make sure each validates to a certain length. Make sure the `displayAsPassword` property of each is set to true as well, so it will just show bullets instead of characters.

Comment: @arunsoorya: If that worked for you, consider accepting this answer. It will improve your reputation here and people will be more likely to answer your questions.